# Map a collection using a predicate and two functions

Tags: functional-programming, language-agnostic, mapping, ternary-operator

While trying to write code in a functional style, I often encounter the scenario where I want to map one collection or stream to another using two functions: one function applied to elements that pass a given predicate and another function applied to elements that fail. Both functions produce a common output, which should be collected for further processing.

Here is a contrived example in Java.

```java
Stream.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux")
      .map(it -> it.startsWith("ba") ? it.toUpperCase() : new StringBuilder(it).reverse())
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

And the same example in Groovy.

```groovy
["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"]
      .collect{ it.startsWith("ba") ? it.toUpperCase() : it.reverse() }
      .each{ println(it) }
```

My question is regarding the conditional (ternary) statement used to implement this mapping. Is there a functional idiom to implement such a mapping without resorting to branching logic?

Comment: You're combining filtering and mapping in the same step which makes it a little harder to see the abstractions. I have a [couple answers that talk about transducers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+transducer) that you might be interested in reading – after understanding them, you'll be able to filter, map, *and* even print while only iterating thru your collection *one* time ^_^

Comment: My understanding is that the _efficiency_ of chaining operations is somewhat language dependent, e.g. Java streams are lazily evaluated, so there is only one iteration per _terminal_ operation (`filter` and `map` are intermediate operations). What I'm more interested in here is chaining a filter where both sides of the predicate are mapped to different functions. In other words, it's a filter that doesn't remove anything but merely divides the elements for separate processing, before recombining them into a single transformed collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can always abstract over an expression with another function. Since you tagged your question *language-agnostic*, I encode my example with Javascript, executable in your favorite browser - I hope this is okay:

```js
// select :: (a -> Boolean, a -> b, a -> b) -> a -> b
const select = (p, f, g) => x => p(x) ? f(x) : g(x);

// mapSelect :: (a -> Boolean, a -> b, a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
const mapSelect = (p, f, g) => xs => xs.map(select(p, f, g));

const reverse = s => s.split("").reverse().join("");
const toUpperCase = s => s.toUpperCase();
const startsWith = s => t => t.indexOf(s) === 0

const xs = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "qux"];

console.log(
  mapSelect(startsWith("ba"), toUpperCase, reverse) (xs)
);
```

Obviously, `mapSelect` doesn't save you from the conditional operator. It is just another layer of abstraction. Since it is not as common as `map`, you increase especially the cognitive load of your coworkers without getting much.

Conclusion: I would stick with the explicit conditional operator instead of disguising the branching logic.

Comment: You might wish to rename `select` to `ifElse`; in fact, [ramda implements it almost exactly the same](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#ifElse).  The `mapSelect` abstraction is a little awkward, `map (ifElse (startsWith ('ba'), toUpperCase, reverse))` is probably declarative enough – otherwise great answer