# Use different map logic based on filter in Java stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a list which can have different values like this

```
("name=xyz", "age=10", "birth=1995", "gender=male")
```

I am only interested in `age` and `birth` fields here. Above is one record. There are multiple such records and some of them can have either age or birth or both or none.

So to find age of the person I do something like this:

```
recordValues.stream().filter(entry -> entry.matches("age") || entry.matches("birth"))
                        .map(entry -> {
                            if (entry.matches("age")) {
                               // parse age and return age as no. of days
                            }
                            else {
                              // parse year and return age as no. of days
                            }
                        })
```

Is there any way to avoid this `if else` or make it more clear? I am just looking for a cleaner code.

Comment: What is the result that you want? I.e. is the age and birth then transformed into a `class`?

Comment: Age in number of days if found

Comment: What is the type of `recordValues`?

Comment: Its List<String>

Comment: @adirohan If it's a list of strings, how do you intend to extract the age or birth values?

Comment: Using regex or split on `=`, I will get the actual value and calculate on that

Comment: On a side note - using ``matches`` is suboptimal in this case - it compiles the same regex pattern multiple times. Just use ``entry.startsWith("age")``.

Comment: @adirohan Or use a map instead of a list.

Comment: Got it, thanks! @nluk Using list because I can't change that.

Comment: Why do you have such a list in the first place? Where do you get it from?

Comment: Its coming from an external jar that I dont control

Comment: This looks like a bad idea, I suggest you to create your own class with proper fields with the proper type. And then before you try to do some fancy stuff, you should convert the input data you're receiving into a `List` of your own class. You'll save a lot of head aches later on

Comment: I asked a very similar question to this, once upon a time: [Map a collection using a predicate and two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44987375/1371329).

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you created a `Person` class and used getters to retrieve the fields.  Fields that aren't filled can have default values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be worth to split the string elements into pairs and then process the split values:

```java
recordValues.stream()
            .map(s -> s.split("=")) // Stream<String[]>
            .filter(arr -> arr.length > 1
                && ("age".equals(arr[0]) || "birth".equals(arr[0])))
            .map(arr -> 365 * ("age".equals(arr[0]) 
                ? Integer.parseInt(arr[1]) 
                : LocalDate.now().getYear()- Integer.parseInt(arr[1]))
            )
            .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or findFirst / findAny
```

However, if birth is presented not just as a year of birth but in more appropriate date format like `yyyy-MM-dd`, the birthdate will have to be processed differently.

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor that mapping function into a method and call it as a method reference:

```
recordValues.stream()
            .filter(entry -> entry.matches("age") || entry.matches("birth"))
            .map(this::ageComputer)

private Integer ageComputer(Entry entry) {
    if (entry.matches("age")) {
        // return age directly
    }
    else {
        // parse the year and return age
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no `Entry` class. The stream elements are strings.